# Getting rid of "git: /usr/local/lib/libz.so.1: no version information available (required by git)"

Tags: git

For every git command I try to run, I get this message. Example:

```
stewie:~# git --version
git: /usr/local/lib/libz.so.1: no version information available (required by git)
git version 1.7.11.4
```

How can I get rid of this?

---

**Edit 1:**

Trying to update `zlib1g`:

```
stewie:/tmp# apt-get install zlib1g
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
zlib1g is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

---

**Edit 2:**

I'm on Debian Lenny (5), so, unfortunately, using `apt-get` isn't that easy.

Comment: Why do you have a libz in /usr/local? Is it perhaps an outdated relic that you can safely remove?

Comment: Hm. Unfortunately I don't know much about Linux. Libs on `/usr/local` have a specific meaning? It's always an "relic" if it's sitting there?

Comment: Well /usr/local means it was compiled locally, not supplied by the OS distribution. Sometimes people do that because they need a newer version than what came with the distribution, then the distribution updates to something newer and the one in /usr/local gets forgotten. That was just a guess though. If you didn't compile zlib yourself, someone else with root access to the machine did. Ask them why... and maybe try `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib git --version` to override it until you get an answer.

Comment: Yeah, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib git --version` seems to work. How do I make it default on git?

Comment: That's not a git configuration, it's a dynamic linker configuration. You could replace `/usr/bin/git` with a wrapper script, but that's more like postponing the problem than fixing it. You need to sort out what's been done in /usr/local and whether the local zlib is still needed by any other applications.

Comment: Any "easy" way to see if there's anyone using it? Any other way to update zlib other than `apt-get`ting?

Comment: You seem to be dodging the question of who put the local zlib there. Asking them about it is seriously the best way to know.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

/usr/local is meant to be used for installation of programs compiled locally, by the machine's administrator. Simple programs just go into /usr/local/bin and are run from there by putting /usr/local/bin into the `PATH` environment variable. This allows the administrator to provide the users access to additional commands, which aren't included in the OS. There's nothing stopping root from installing new things into /usr/bin but the convention is that /usr/bin is managed by the OS distributor's packaging tools, and keeping local stuff separate makes things a little less confusing.

Sometimes a local program needs a library that isn't provided by the OS distributor, and the library goes into /usr/local/lib and everything works.

When there's a version conflict - the OS supplied libz.so of version X but a local program needs libz.so version X+1 or needs libz.so to be compiled with a special option - things start to get complicated. Installing the newer library in /usr/local/lib is probably OK at first.

Every program looks for libraries based on `/etc/ld.so.conf` and if /usr/lib is given priority there, the /usr/local programs won't find the newer library that they need. So /usr/local/lib is usually given priority. Older programs finding a newer library is usually not a problem because the libraries are backward-compatible.

Years later, after a few OS upgrades, the library in /usr/lib is now version X+2 and the one in /usr/local/lib is still version X+1, and now programs from /usr/bin are loading the old /usr/local/lib version, and misbehaving. This can probably be fixed by removing the old library. The /usr/local/bin program that needed version X+1 will find version X+2 in /usr/lib and work fine. But only if the need for a newer version was the reason for installing version X+1 locally in the first place.

To probe for potential problems before doing the removal, look for anything under /usr/local that uses libz.

```
ldd /usr/local/bin/* /usr/local/sbin/* | less +/libz
```

If you find anything that references libz, try running it with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib` to make sure it still works. Assuming nothing breaks, remove the local libz files (by moving them to a backup location so you can undo this if you have to)

```
mkdir /root/local-libz-backup
mv /usr/local/lib/libz* /root/local-libz-backup
ldconfig
```

Comment: Awesome answer. php is also relying on libz.so.1, so I'll postpone this fix. But clearly this is the way to go. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I have DirectAdmin on my server and this [this guide](http://www.vr.org/kb/3182/orusrorlocalorliborlibzso1-no-version-information-available-required-by-python.html) solved my problem.

(copied from page)

If you see the error

```
/usr/local/lib/libz.so.1: no version information available (required by python)
```

it has to do with the version of libz installed. The reason for the current version has to do with the version of libz that libxml2 requires. A newer version of both will resolve the issue, but due to many reported issues with this update, we reverted to the older version of libz and libxml2. Note that the warning is not going to hurt anything, so it can be ignored.

If you still wish to update libz and libxml2 to their newer versions to avoid the message, type:

```
cd /usr/local/directadmin/custombuild
./build update
perl -pi -e 's/zlib:1.2.3:.*/zlib:1.2.5:/' versions.txt
perl -pi -e 's/libxml2:2.7.6:.*/libxml2:2.7.8:/' versions.txt
./build update_data
./build zlib
./build libxml2
./build php n
```

Answer (score 2):

This method works for my case, add the following line your .bash_profile:

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

then run `. ~/.bash_profile`

Answer (score 1):

Export `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` with the git lib path for resolving the error:

```
libz.so.1: no version information available
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this warning for a related but slightly different reason.

If you compile your own zlib and override LDSHARED during the build, but you fail to include the [--version-script argument to the linker](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/v1.2.13/configure#L230), your new libz.so.1 will have no symbol versions... And then pretty much everything that relies on zlib will elicit the "no version information available" warning from the dynamic linker.

The fix is not to override LDSHARED, or to make sure it includes the appropriate flags.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you need to update your build prerequisites.

Comment: And how/why should I proceed, exactly?

Comment: google for building git. There you will find a set of `sudo apt-get install` parameters. An easy way is to uninstall libz and remove it. Then reinstall it.

Comment: I've just compiled/installed git. It's a freaking Debian Lenny (5) server, so the repositories aren't maintained anymore. I've to set some backport or other workarounds in order to download packages. I've already had to run `make install` with `CFLAGS="-liconv"` as `iconv` wasn't being found. And I've updated my answer to show my `apt-get install zlib1g` output.